# Firestore login Authorization Error 400 invalid request

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm following a lab at https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/2767?parent=catalog, and I encounter this error during "firebase login --no-localhost". It keeps returning "Authorization Error 400: Invalid_request, Required parameter is missing: response_type". I tried to google for answers but could not find any leads.

Has anyone managed to clear this lab? Is there some missing steps I need to perform?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should go to your firebase console -> Authentication -> Sign-in method and enable the Sign-in method you are using.

Comment: sorry Khaled....I like to try again but google said my quota has reached....this google lab is nonsense....

Comment: Totally agreed....